# How to maintain states of selection on back button

Tags: javascript

I am using HTML and JavaScript to write Android APP, but I have a problem that when go back from current page to the previous page, the page is reloaded and the selection and setting when I made in the first goes to default.

For example: On the first page user can select country and city and then navigate to second page.

If user clicks on back button (which calls `window.history.back();` or `href="javascript:history.back(-1);"`)
, then all the selection he made are lost and default selections are shown.

It works fine in native browser of Android.
How to maintain state of selection?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if it is so important you can store it in HTML5 localSotrage on selectbox.change().  And assign it back on document load

Answer (score 0):

You need to make dummy history to disable history back button.

```
var originalHash = document.hash || "#dummyMain"
location.assign("#dummyBack")
location.assign(originalHash)
window.addEventListener("popstate",function(){
  if(location.hash == "#dummyBack"){
    window.history.pushState(null,null,originalHash)
  }else{
    originalHash = location.hash
  } 
});
```

The code above create dummy page history and checks if page transitions are occurred via history back button or not and if so,force page move to current page again to stop history back action.

Since You didn't put any code in the question,It's hardly possible to say it will work or not but I guess once you load this code,it should disable all page back action.

If you are using PC/Mac to use this site,please try to open developper tools/firebug javascript console and copy/paste the code and press history back button to see how it works.

Comment: Thanks for reply!
I used your code in my page, but it did not solved the problem. If you can tell me exactly how to use this method. Give some example. Thank you!

Comment: I putted your code in the top of JavaScript file and at the end of this file I have alerted (alert('Code Executed Again');), and imported the JS file in JPS file, at first time alert is shown (it is normal), but when navigate to the second page and come back, the alert also shown, it means that code executed again, the same as first time. But in some mobile phone browser the second alert will not shown.

Comment: > If you are using PC/Mac to use this site,please try to open developper tools/firebug javascript console and copy/paste the code and press history back button to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I find a good way to maintain the data of previous page, which use `localStorage` store the data as key value before leaving this page and again when come back to this page you can get your data again from localStorage` and display it.

Because the data which is loaded by AJAX will be last on history back.

Hope this help someone may has this problem.